# Improving speed in winform application and WCF with Caching

Tags: winforms, wcf, oracle, caching, memcached

We provide a critical application for a customer. It's a clickonce winforms application which consumes several WCF services which communicates with an Oracle Database.
The service is hosted with Oracle Application Server with two Web Cache Servers in front for load balancing. The Database is on another separate machine.

Thing is, the application has now poor performance and we need to speed it up. We have tried many techniques: optimize queries with adding indexes when analyzing explain plans, reducing service calls from client and profiling the client application for pitfalls.

But I would really like two set up a caching layer over the database or the WCF. The data is critical and changed quite often so it's necessary to get the latest data at all requests.
So when data changes in the database the cache should immediately be expired. The queries are complex with up two 14-15 joins...

How is the right way to do this and which tools/frameworks should I use? I have heard of memcached.. is this good?

Comment: Have you profiled the application to work out where the time is being spent? Throwing complexity at a solution until you know where the biggest bang for buck is can be counter-productive

Comment: I have, and retrieving data from database is probably the biggest problem

Comment: Does all data access go through your service or can the data change in the database out of band?

Comment: Everything goes through this webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code sees all updates to the data you can have a very effective caching layer as the cache can be updated at the same time as the database.

With your requirement for absolute cache coherency you need to make sure all servers see the same cache. There are two approaches you could take:

1. Have a cache server which uses something like the ASP.NET cache which the application servers talk to to get and update the data
2. Use a caching product to maintain the cache

If you use a caching product there are a number on market: [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [gemfire](http://www.vmware.com/products/vfabric-gemfire/overview.html), [coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html), [Windows Server AppFabric Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) and more

The nice thing about AppFabric Caching (project formally known as Velocity) is that it is free with Windows Server and is very .NET friendly (although it is newer than some of the others and so you might say less proven)

Answer (score 1):

Before adding a new tool you should make sure you're correctly using all of the Oracle caching that is available to you.

There's the [buffer cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/memory.htm#i10221), [PL/SQL function result cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#BABFHACJ), [client query result cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/memory.htm#BGBBIACC), [sql query result cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/memory.htm#PFGRF10121), [materialized views](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6002.htm), and bind variables will help cache query plans.